# Authentication issues with django-webpack-loader with vuejs and django restframework and restauth

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I created a frontend with vue.js using vue cli and webpack and the backend using django restframework where I am also implementing social authentication for google using restauth. Before I used the django webpack, the login and logout would work fine and as expected. (I should mention that I was using tokenauthentication) in my settings.py, file I had both the sessionauthentication as well as tokenauthentication enabled in the restframework authentication possibilities. The two settings being enabled never caused any trouble. However, after using the django webpack loader to render the frontend vue files using django templates, I would continuously get an error that said my csrf token was not present. The login would work fine in this case if I removed the sessionauthentication option out of the settings.py file however.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

https://medium.com/@rodrigosmaniotto/integrating-django-and-vuejs-with-vue-cli-3-and-webpack-loader-145c3b98501a

I used the above blog to implement the webpack loader functionality

I removed the 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', line from my settings.py after using the django-webpack-loader and the issue was resolved

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
)
}
```

I basically changed it like below:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',

)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you are probably using axios, you need to include these two lines in your `main.js`

```
/* configure axios to forward the csrftoken back to Django on POST requests */
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
```

Comment: Hey! This worked! But could you please tell me why I needed to add this code to make it work but didn't need to do this when I wasn't using the webpack loader and the app seemed to work fine?

Comment: Maybe you were not using POST requests with axios? This is not something related to webpack loader. It's related to using axios to make requests. With these settings you are telling axios to read the xsrf cookie (with the name that Django uses to send the cookie) and include it's value as a header in all requests sent.

Comment: I was using axios before as well. So I can only guess that this issue occurred right after using the django-webpack-loader because then django would render the the vue files itself and kind of create a proxy route so that my vue.js files were rendered on the same localhost port as the one on which django was running too. Could this be a reason or even close to an explanation for this?

Comment: If before using django-webpack-loader you were using webpack directly to serve the front-end files in a different port then yes, your requests were authenticated using "token authentication" (because session authentication only works under the same port) and Django didn't even try to use session authentication.